# Using default ActionResult/page without having to include it in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC and entity framework and I'm using the following code to bring back everything from a table and display it on screen

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if (id  == null) {
            return View(db.DDLs.ToList());
        } else {
            var drafts = db.DDLs.Where(d => d.DDLTypeID == id).ToList();
            return View(drafts);
        }
    }
```

Typing this URL in shows the contents of the whole table as I'd expect.

localhost:2378/DDL/

index being the default ActionResult/routes so I thought that using MVC/EF I could use

localhost:2378/DDL/1

to bring back just records where DDLTypeID = 1, but instead I have to include the default ActionResult/route like so.

localhost:2378/DDL/index/1

Is there a way to use

localhost:2378/DDL/1

or have I had another fundamental misunderstanding of MVC/EF?

I'm using the default routes created by Visual Studio if that helps.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you should consider keeping the action in the url to eliminate confusion and don't overload your action like that

Comment: You can always add specific routes e.g. `url: "DDL/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "DDL", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Answer (score 0):

You can map multiple patterns of the route to the same action method. 
Routing is only related to ASP.NET MVC, it has nothing to do with EF.

Refer this website: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc